# Can かなり be used with ーそうだ？

Tags: grammar, usage

I want to make the sentence, "You two seem pretty close." and I've come up with 二人はかなり仲が良さそうだ。 Now I'm wondering if かなり is correct or natural to use here with そうだ and if it's even necessary. Thanks.